# What is the difference between 'can', 'could' and 'would you mind' in asking questions?

Tags: meaning, differences, questions

For me these 3 have the same meaning, but i just could not differentiate what the subtle difference between them, maybe 'would you mind' is more polite then the other two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my ears, yes, "Would you mind?" is generally the most polite. "Can you?" and "Could you?" are still fairly polite.

Obviously, there are nuances that are difficult to summarize. For example, if you're at McDonald's arguably the most polite way to order would be, "Could I get a quarter pounder with cheese?" If you asked, "Would you mind giving me a quarter pounder with cheese?" it might come off as almost sarcastic because it implies what your asking for could be burdensome to the other person. In this case, what you're asking for has nothing to do with them going above or beyond their normal work duties.

If you *did* want to ask for something a bit out of the ordinary, then "Would you mind" would sound perfectly polite. For example, "Would you mind putting a little extra ice in my drink?"

Anyway, a non-native speaker shouldn't sweat the details too much. As long as you're not giving commands or using "I want you to" then you'll be fine most of the time.

Comment: I notice you suggest using "Could I get a quarter pounder with cheese?" instead of "Could you give me a quarter pounder with cheese?". I think there's something to it. In fact, I'll almost always use "I" in this kind of context, as in "I'd like to have a quarter pounder with cheese." or simply "I'll have a quarter pounder with cheese."

Comment: I agree that "Could you give me a quarter pounder with cheese?" is more or less equally polite. However, "I'd like to have a quarter pounder with cheese," while certainly polite, comes off as just a tad more blunt to me. Granted, we're splitting hairs at this point. Of course intuitions will vary based on local culture. (Mine are based on politeness norms of the U.S. South.)

Comment: Could you tell me what's so "blunt" about "I'd like to have..."? To me, it's polite enough to be uttered when ordering meals. At least, it's more polite than "I'll have...", which I think _is_ also a very common way of ordering meals.

Comment: Any difference in this context is very subtle, which is why I described it merely as "a tad." On the whole, yes, it is certainly polite. But if I had to justify my intuition I'd say it's because it informs the other of one's desire as opposed to sort of asking for permission.